# Excel move even cells to separate column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been given a spreadsheet that has a single column with odd numbered rows containing a value and even numbered rows containing an associated date. I would like to convert this into a format where the odd row values have their assocated date in the same row but a separate column, e.g.

```
|ABC1234  |     |ABC1234|13-Dec-13|
|---------|     |-------|---------|
|13-Dec-13|     |ABC1235|14-Dec-13|
|---------|     |-------|---------|
|ABC1235  |     |ABC1236|15-Dec-13|
|---------| -> 
|14-Dec-13|
|---------|
|ABC1236  |
|---------|
|15-Dec-13|
```

Is this possible just using the formulas or would a macro be required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feels like a hack, but assuming you start at the top of the excel doc, you can use this formula:

```
    =INDIRECT("A" & (2*ROW()))
```

Where "A" is the column name of the original data (the column with the alternating data types). INDIRECT basically concatenates "A" with the value of 2*ROW(). And, ROW() gives the current row number of the cell. If you need to offset it due to headers or something like that, you can add or subtract an offset after 2*ROW() (in order to change the row number).

So, you would use

```
    =INDIRECT("A" & (2*ROW()-1))
```

to make the ABC.... column and then use

```
    =INDIRECT("A" & (2*ROW()))
```

to make the date column